# Most efficient way to retrieve master/detail (nested) data

Tags: sql-server, performance

My question is somewhat of a follow-up on this one: [Efficient Way To Query Nested Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/316967/efficient-way-to-query-nested-data). However, I'd like to generalize it a bit, and potentially update it as it's been 6 years and there may be new and better alternatives (?).

I have a typical master/detail relationship in a MS SQL Server database (although I believe DB-agnostic answers could help anyone because this is a very generic problem).

- MasterTable has MasterId key, then additional master-level fields.
- DetailTable has a DetailId key, a MasterId foreign key, then additional detail-level fields.

I am looking for the **best-performing** approach to read from the database and load such a nested structure in memory (into data objects). I realize the answer may be "it depends", in which case what does it depend on?

These are the alternatives I have come up with:

1. "Classical" SQL full query - I mean something in the lines of:

SELECT * 
FROM MasterTable 
JOIN DetailTable ON MasterTable.Id = DetailTable.MasterId

[This, if I am not mistaken, is what ORMs will create if performing an eager load of the equivalent data model objects... for instance, using .Include in Entity Framework]

The drawback of this approach is the data duplication which results from having to "flatten" this hierarchical structure, repeating all needed MasterTable fields for each DetailTable record. Depending on the total size of the result set and of the needed fields from MasterTable, this can give terrible performance (both on the database itself and, after that, on the transport of all that data to your process... plus I am not sure the final data object materialization is any quicker either).

2. SQL full query to XML - At least in SQL Server, I mean something in the lines of:

SELECT MasterTable.*,
(SELECT * FROM DetailTable
 WHERE MasterTable.Id = DetailTable.MasterId FOR XML PATH('Detail'), TYPE)
FROM MasterTable FOR XML PATH('Master')

I am not fully sure what SQL Server does under the hood, but the output is hierarchical and, as such, there is no data duplication (although there is some XML formatting process cost, I guess, and the XML tags as additional data). There is then the added step of de-serializing the XML result to the data objects, but that isn't very costly either (neither CPU-wise nor in lines of code, as it's typically already built-in within most programming frameworks).

From my experience, this approach gives much better results than the first one, and the differences increase as the number of joined tables, size of the result set, etc... increases.

3. SQL query per table and join in memory - I mean something in the lines of sending 2 different queries:

SELECT * FROM MasterTable, and
SELECT * FROM DetailTable

and then perform the data object hierarchy materialization in memory. This can be done efficiently, as was provided as an answer in the original link, with one pass on each result set:

*Query for all masters ordered by MasterId then query for all Details also ordered by MasterId. Then, with two nested loops, iterate the master data and create a new Master object for each row in the main loop, and iterate the details while they have the same MasterId as the current Master object and populate its _details collection in the nested loop.*

This takes 2 queries (or N for each additional details table needed), but the total size of the result sets and what is transferred to the calling process is as small as can be.

Up to very recently (I was not aware of the FOR XML capabilities of SQL Server), in 9 out of 10 scenarios I had found option 3 to be always significantly better than 1 (which I rarely ever use, really)... but now I am curious about option 2 in real-world scenarios with a significant amount of data involved, so will do some quick comparison in the next project I have the need.

What is your opinion/experience with FOR XML, what do you reckon in general regarding these alternatives, and is there any other you would recommend instead?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No idea, but IMHO the database connection should be smart enough to transparently perform the deduplication. It sounds damn trivial for data like `(m1, d1), (m1, d2), (m1, d3), ...`.

Comment: Is the network speed a limiting factor in your setup? I would put the work on increasing network speed instead of redesigning application/queries. Duplicated master data should compress well so adding network compression might be the easiest solution.